# Registering and using multiple variables in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to pop VM instances, put them into different host groups (say webservers and devops/admin machines) and install what is needed on them in one single playbook.

I don't know what IP addresses, for instance, GCP will give these instances, and so i am trying to capture them in a variable for use later on in the playbook. I can capture them fine by using "register" but using them is proving tricky. For instance if I do.

```
- name: création des adresses statiques
      gcp_compute_address:
          name: "{{ item }}"
          state: present
          region: "{{ region }}"
          project: "{{ gcp_project }}"
          auth_kind: "{{ gcp_cred_kind }}"
          service_account_file: "{{ gcp_cred_file }}"
          scopes:
            - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
      loop:
        - adresse-1
        - adresse-2
        - adresse-3
        - adresse-4
        - adresse-5
      register: address
```

The best way i have figured out to use these variables later on is:

```
network_interfaces: 
      - network: "{{ network.name }}"
        access_configs:
        - name: 'External NAT'
          type: 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT'
          nat_ip:
            - "{{ address.results[0].address }}"
            - "{{ address.results[1].address }}"
            - "{{ address.results[2].address }}"
```

Which fails miserably.

Please help ? How can I use the range of addresses I have created ?
I am going nuts over this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory) to the group *webservers* and proceed with the next play

```
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: webservers
      loop: "{{ address.results|json_query('[*].address') }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ groups['webservers'] }}"

- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
    - name: Configure cluster
      ...
```

The tasks below split the hosts into two groups

```
- set_fact:
    my_hosts: "{{ address.results|json_query('[*].address') }}"
- add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: webservers1
  loop: "{{ my_hosts[0:(my_hosts|length / 2)|int] }}"
- add_host:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    groups: webservers2
  loop: "{{ my_hosts[(my_hosts|length / 2)|int:my_hosts|length] }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups['webservers1'] }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups['webservers2'] }}"
```

There is also [GCE Dynamic Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#gce-dynamic-inventory) and other 100+ [gcp modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#google). You might want to start with [Google Cloud Platform Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#google-cloud-platform-guide).

---

<sup>FWIW, [Ansible 2 Cloud Automation Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/178829582X) covers leading providers incl. GCP.</sup>

Comment: Fantastic ! Thanks ! I'm at home so i just did a quick debug.msg and it gives me a list of addresses. How wouls you go about splitting those into two groups ?

Comment: Define the condition to split the list. I mean, how would you like to split it?

Comment: I don't really care how it's split. I'd just like two machines in one group and three in the other

Comment: Just saw your answer. That rocks ! Thanks ever so much !!